# Finding a substring in another column

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

What I am trying to do is to check whether or not a specific column contains a substring from another specific column.

The code I currently have is;

```
SELECT *
FROM myLog
WHERE header LIKE SUBSTRING(body,1,5)
```

I need to see if the first 5 characters of the `body` column are in the `header` column of the same row.

Comment: whats wrong with the query? except that you can use `header = SUBSTRING(body,1,5)`

Comment: `LIKE '%'+ SUBSTRING(body,1,5)  +'%'`

Comment: The query runs but does not return any results, however if I run something more specific like;  `SELECT body,header FROM myLog
WHERE header LIKE '%d6453%';` it will return some rows. Those rows also have d6453 as the first 5 characters of the `body`.

Comment: @PaulV - you might have white space in your body column. You can ignore that in the query using `LTRIM`. See my update below for a full query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `%` sign which is a wild card that works with `LIKE` in the `WHERE` clause. The clause here indicates `header` should contain the first 5 characters that the `body` starts with.

```
SELECT * 
FROM myLog
WHERE header LIKE '%' + SUBSTRING(body,1,5) + '%'
```

You can also use the `LEFT` function instead of `SUBSTRING`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM myLog
WHERE header LIKE '%' + LEFT(body,5) + '%'
```

---

> The query runs but does not return any results, however if I run something more specific like; SELECT body,header FROM myLog WHERE header LIKE '%d6453%'; it will return some rows. Those rows also have d6453 as the first 5 characters of the body

Sounds like you could have whitespace in the `body` column. Try adding `LTRIM`, which removes white space on the left side, to the query like so.

```
SELECT header, body
FROM myLog
WHERE header LIKE '%' + LEFT(LTRIM(body),5) + '%'
```